# Wordpress WPDB SQL - How to query two meta_key

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to query two meta keys at once using my code:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta

WHERE meta_key = "listing_location_enabled"
AND meta_value = "yes"

AND meta_key = "listing_location_country"
AND meta_value = "INDIA"
```

But is not showing any results. Is my query correct?

Comment: Try this:   SELECT * FROM WP_POSTMETA

WHERE (META_KEY = "LISTING_LOCATION_ENABLED"
AND META_VALUE = "YES")

OR( META_KEY = "LISTING_LOCATION_COUNTRY"
AND META_VALUE = "INDIA")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your query is not correct. (Those meta tables are a notorious pain in the xxx neck to use correctly.) You need this query pattern. It joins wp_postmeta to itself.

```sql
SELECT lle.post_id,
       lle.meta_value listing_location_enabled.
       llc.meta_value listing_location_country
 
  FROM wp_postmeta lle
  JOIN wp_postmeta llc  ON lle.post_id = llc.post_id
 WHERE lle.meta_key = 'listing_location_enabled'
   AND lle.meta_value = 'yes'
   AND llc.meta_key = 'listing_location_country'
   AND llc.meta_value = 'INDIA'
```

Or, better yet if you're writing code for WordPress, use its [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) facility.

```php
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'lle' => array(
            'key' => 'listing_location_enabled',
            'value' => 'yes',
        ),
        'llc' => array(
            'key' => 'listing_location_country',
            'value' => 'INDIA',
        ), 
    )
) );
```

Comment: Wordpress Sql is needed at the moment, i know using wp_query or get_posts. Thanks